# error: could not start the command. lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Tags: errors, luatex, miktex, windows

I have just installed texmaker 4.4.1 and MikTeX 64bit in my laptop. When I use pdflaTeX everything seems to be working fine, however when I try to switch to LuaLaTex I get the message shown in the title:

> could not start the command. lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

no log file is produced, the process stops and no pdf file is produced. I changed the pdf viewer from the internal to external with no luck. I compared texmaker setings with those on my PC installation, where everything is working properly but I couldn't find anything wrong.

any ideas?

Comment: Update: When I try to compile with XeLaTeX, everything works fine, unless the filename is in greek, where I get the same error message: "could not start the command. lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Can you try with latin filenames?